# apt-get update: Err https://mirror.umd.edu -> server certificate verification failed

Tags: apt, updates, certificates

Today I tried executed the command: apt-get update. But there seems to be a problem, because I get error-messages like these:

```
Err https://mirror.umd.edu trusty/main Sources
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Err https://mirror.umd.edu trusty/restricted Sources
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

etc. And then:

W: Failed to fetch https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

W: Failed to fetch https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

etc.

I guess this problem is because I don't have a file called 'ca-certificates.crt' in that folder. I looked also on another server with Ubuntu 14.04 on it, but this certicate file doesn't excist there either. So, where can I find/download this crt-file?

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their certificate is invalid as of the other day - they forgot to renew their SSL Certificate

Simply visiting the URL with Firefox and checking the certificate warning shows you this.

> mirror.umd.edu uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate expired on 19/04/17 13:00.
>
> The current time is 21/04/17 14:31.

You can either

- wait a bit
- Change repository
- Change the URLs in your apt sources to `http://` (safe enough fi GPG signing is performed)
- Set `Verify-Peer` in your `apt.conf` settings to `false` (not recommended as a set-and-forget solution)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For this moment I did choose the 3rd option you gave. However, if they don't gonna update their security-certificate, I want to change the repository. But therefore I have to look for a list with https://-repository's. But, for now, I wait a bit.

Comment: In good news - they updated it as of today, so you can turn off that setting now.